# How to test a USB device created using Startup Disk Creator without restarting?

Tags: startup-disk-creator

I made an Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit bootable USB device using [Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/%E2%80%8E). However, it did not give me a message that the device is bootable and I could test it, which it usually gives if the disk was successfully created as a bootable device.

Is there anyway, including using virtualization softwares, that I could test this bootable device without having to reboot my machine(I am too lazy to do that :-P)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware and VirtualBox don't directly support booting a Virtual machine from a Physical USB Drive.  Only Qemu supports booting from a Physical USB Drive.

VirtualBox (with the use of vboxmanage.exe tool)can Boot your USB Drive.  See [here](http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/test-bootable-usb-drive-without-restarting-your-computer/)

[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Index.html) is a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.

If you want to to that under Windows then use [MobaLiveCD](http://mobalivecd.mobatek.net/en/)

Comment: It requires the vboxmanage.exe tool to create a `.vmdk` file. Isn't there a linux package for this?

Comment: As far as I know NO.